# search for multiple buttons by name by c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have 24 buttons, each button represents a seat. When I sell tickets for a movie theater, I keep the seat number in the database (eg 1 ,2 ,3) and the texts of the buttons are written as 1-2-3-4. After pulling the seat numbers from the database, I want to compare them with the buttons and make that button 'enable=false' if I sold it. But I don't know how to check the buttons against their names (or in a different way). When the program starts, previously sold seats, ie buttons, should not be selected again. What comparison should I make for this?

I wrote this method to pull seat numbers

```
        public void getSeats()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string sql = "select Seat from Ticket";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                foreach(DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    list.Add(item["Seat"].ToString());
                }

            }

        }
```

I wrote a code like below and this is what I needed. Thanks.

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
     {
       foreach (string butonName in list) {
          if (control is Button && control.Text == butonName)
               control.Enabled = false;
      }        
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use UI state as a canonical representation of application data.

Comment: You don't need `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataSet` - let alone a single `DataTable`. Rather than use `SqlDataReader` directly consider using strongly-typed entity objects and an ORM like Entity Framework.

Comment: For context, is this a school/homework/course assignment - or is this an actual production system you work on?

Comment: it's an homework, and I am inexperienced for c# @Dai

Comment: If those buttons all sit in the same container you can get a list of them from the Controls collection Where Name ==  .. && Where TypeOf(control) = Button